# Change background image of div when mouse has specific class

Tags: javascript, css, click, background-image

I'm creating an interactive art piece, which people can collaborate on. What I want is that there is a library of icons people can use. And when clicking on them, the mouse gets a class and thus when clicking on a specific cell in the table, the cell will get the icon as their background image.

(Now I know I will need a database etc, but that's for later. First things first.)

I did something similar a long time ago, but I don't know how to edit this in order to work for this project:

```
function nextPic() {

if ( $('html,body').css('cursor').indexOf('cursor2.png') > 0 ) 
{
  counter += 1;
  if (counter > myPictures.length - 1) {
   // counter = 0;
  }
  else {
    element.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + myPictures[counter] + ")";        
  }
}
```

It just works according to the image on the cursor. Not ideal at all, it bugged ALL the time.

I've looked at a code for pixel art, which (kind of) does what needs t one done. But not quite.

The pixel art fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/bxstmufj/

Comment: I would say usually you would have an onClick event on the icons and save what icon someone clicked on in a variable. You can then call on this variable when they click on the art/canvas thus putting the icon they had previously picked in the spot they clicked on the art/canvas.

Comment: You've explained exactly what I need in all the right words. Thank you so much hahaha. You don't happen to know a nice example, right? I've been searching but haven't found any yet.

Comment: Glad it helped, instead of me doing it was easier to find someone else that already nailed it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is an example of someone doing what you want but instead of in a table grid in a canvas. Mad props to them for putting this out:
http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/

After the basic drawing on a canvas they add the ability to pick colors. Notice how they save the picked color into a variable that is then called on for the canvas reDraw() function.

The same thing can be done with icons. Simply having an onClick event for whatever icon is clicked just like they did with colors (in their case they chose mousedown event):

```
$('#choosePurpleSimpleColors').mousedown(function(e){
    curColor_simpleColors = colorPurple;
});
```

That is the event handler they put on the purple button for example. You can see this by inspecting the element (button) then on the right click Event Handlers then go to the mousedown event and then you can click on the javascript file location where this code is. (All of this done in chrome inspect{right click, then pick inspect})

Now if you did not want to do it on a canvas but instead a a table/grid all you would do is set onClick events for the cells. They would then call on the color/icon variable and set them for that cell.

Let me know if you would like an example for a grid/table. The canvas is a bit more of a complex answer but I suspect it is what you really prefer. The second example and beyond is really what you want so you could also pick icons to insert.

```js
context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext("2d");

$('#canvas').mousedown(function(e){
  var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
  
  paint = true;
  addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
  redraw();
});

$('#canvas').mousemove(function(e){
  if(paint){
    addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop, true);
    redraw();
  }
});

$('#canvas').mouseup(function(e){
  paint = false;
});

$('#canvas').mouseleave(function(e){
  paint = false;
});

var clickX = new Array();
var clickY = new Array();
var clickDrag = new Array();
var paint;

function addClick(x, y, dragging)
{
  clickX.push(x);
  clickY.push(y);
  clickDrag.push(dragging);
}

function redraw(){
  context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); // Clears the canvas
  
  context.strokeStyle = "#df4b26";
  context.lineJoin = "round";
  context.lineWidth = 5;
   
  for(var i=0; i < clickX.length; i++) {  
    context.beginPath();
    if(clickDrag[i] && i){
      context.moveTo(clickX[i-1], clickY[i-1]);
     }else{
       context.moveTo(clickX[i]-1, clickY[i]);
     }
     context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
     context.closePath();
     context.stroke();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="490" height="220" style="border: solid 1px black;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!

```
<div id="p1" class="pen"></div>
<div id="p2" class="pen"></div>


  <div id="art">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="pixel"></div>
      <div class="pixel"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
icon = '(icon.png)'

$('#p1').click(function (){
    icon = "icon2.png";
    alert(icon);
});


$('#p2').click(function (){
    icon = "icon3.png";
    alert(icon);
});


// onclick function classes 
  $(".pixel").click(function() {
        //function that changes background to url
    // $(this).css('background-image', var(icon));
    // $(this).css("background-image", "url(" + icon")");
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(" +icon +")");
});
```

```
#art {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 1px;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.pixel {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: white;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 1px;
  height: 25px;
  background-size: contain;
}

.pen {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Oh my bad didn't see this. Yea it looks like you are going down the path for changing the div's nicely!

Comment: hahaha that's perfectly fine. Your code was incredibly helpful anyways. But yes, I'm glad I solved it somehow. Now to the next problem! Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about using a class to set varied colors; a class would infer that they are all the same. You'd have to use ids to differentiate. You could pass the id and the color that you want to change the background to  to a function and work it that way. Or you might opt to put the colors in an array and use the index number?

I made a basic example using the squares in your fiddle, to give an idea. As you can see, I only assigned one of the two a background value using css. The function can be tweaked to change background image if you want to use images instead of colors of course..

Hope this helps

```js
function setPenColour(id, pixel) {
  var myDiv = document.getElementById(id);
  myDiv.style.backgroundColor = pixel;
}
```

```css
#p1 {
  background-color: grey;
}

#art {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 1px;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.pixel {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: white;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 1px;
  height: 25px;
}

.pen {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="p1" class="pen" onclick="setPenColour(id, '#00FF00')" ;></div>
<div id="p2" class="pen" style="background-color:blue;" onclick="setPenColour(id, 'red')"></div>
```

Comment: This does indeed work, however the idea is to click on a specific icon, and the 'color in' a grid with that specific icon. And if one wants a different one, click on it and continue 'colouring in'. Instead of the id's changing color, it it should allow the user to color in the blank grid. I edited a bit so it changes the backgroundImage rather than the color! Maybe this is more clearer?